# PHP Count files and use in Mootools

Tags: php, variables, count

Hello i wanna use this php code to count jpg files in a dic.

```
$directory = "../images/team/harry/";
if (glob($directory . "*.jpg") != false)
{
 $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*.jpg"));
 echo $filecount;
}
else
{
 echo 0;
}
```

How can i use now $filecount in my mootool script?
Best regards Matthias.

Comment: Use Ajax for get your value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language. Mootools is JavaScript, right?

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request

```
var myRequest = new Request({
    url: 'http://yourserver.com/jpgs.php',
    onSuccess: function(res, xml){
        console.log(res);
    }
});

myRequest.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to echo out $filecount as inline javascript or you can request the result over Ajax.